# Where does one create a new organization on "Google Cloud Platform"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Cloud Platform

I go to https://console.cloud.google.com/, then go to Identity and Organization.

It says "To view this page, select an organization."

I did not yet create an organization, so I am expecting a button "create new organization" to appear on this page, but there is only "select", and when I click on "select", nothing happens.

An organization seems to be required for many tasks (for example, creating a new projects requires me to put it in an organization), but how can one create a new organization using Google Cloud Platform?

[image: Google dashboard without a "create organization" button]

Answer (score 7):

You need to have either a Gsuite or Cloud Identity account before you can [create an Org](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization). If you're on free trial then you don't need an Org to [create a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project).